# Accessing images in a .JAR file

Tags: java, image, jar

I have a set of 5 images in my program. The program will be compiled as a single `.JAR` file, so they need to be read from it as such. However, when I make a call like

```
images = new ArrayPP<ImageIcon>(
          new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bha/resources/Portal Test Chamber 17 - Part 1.png")),
          new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bha/resources/Portal Test Chamber 17 - Part 2.png")),
          new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bha/resources/Portal Test Chamber 17 - Part 3.png")),
          new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bha/resources/revit logo - glass.png")),
          new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bha/resources/The All-Knowing Octopus.png")));
```

which works for the icons in `JMenuItem`s (for example, `jMenuItem.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bha/resources/icon.png")));` will always work) and when testing in an IDE, but returns as `null` when compiled as a `JAR` file.

Comment: stupid question but, you are sure the images got copied to the jar file, right?

Comment: Assumed jar file named bha.jar, Try with ./resources/Portal Test Chamber 17 - Part 1.png"

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy yes, I decompiled the `.JAR` file and checked

Comment: @Senthil They're in a `.JAR` file called "Blue Husky Art", in the package `bha.resources`. I'll try your dot-hack method

Comment: @Senthil That suggestion does not work in both the IDE and `.JAR` file

Comment: I am totally going by my gut here, but you can try renaming the files to not have spaces in them.

Comment: thank you. I came upon the same idea, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that getResource returns a URL, i'm guessing that it's not liking the spaces. As a test, i'd try doing

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(URLEncoder.encode("/bha/resources/Portal Test Chamber 17 - Part 1.png", "UTF-8"))),
```

Comment: That still throws a `NullPointerException`. The result is unchanged.

Comment: However, that gave me the idea to use spaceless names, and that worked. Thank you.