# In java, how do you retrieve images from a jar file?

Tags: java, reference, jar

I've been having problems exporting my java project to a jar (from Eclipse). There is a file that I've included in the jar named `images`. It contains all of the image files used by my project. The problem is, my references to those images only work when the project *isn't* in jar form. I can't figure out why and I'm wondering if I need to change the wording of the image references. This is what I'm doing to reference images:

```
    URL treeURL = null;
    Image tree = null;
    File pathToTheTree = new File("images/tree.png");
    try {
        treeURL = pathToTheTree.toURL();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        tree = ImageIO.read(treeURL);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Most likely it is a simple problem, as I'm a beginner at coding. What do I need to change to make these references work when it's all in a jar?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870517/exporting-images-with-jar-in-eclipse-java & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698373/accessing-images-in-a-jar-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed simple: you use the various `getResource()` methods in `java.lang.Class` and `java.lang.ClassLoader`. For example, in your app, you could just write

```
treeURL = getClass().getResource("/images/tree.png");
```

This would find the file in an `images` directory at the root of the jar file. The nice thing about the `getResource()` methods is that they work whether the files are in a jar or not -- if the `images` directory is a real directory on disk, this will still work (as long as the parent of `images` is part of your class path.)

Comment: This solved it, thank you so much! But now it doesn't run in Eclipse and only in jar form... Any way I can rearrange files or code to fix that?

Comment: You just need to make sure /images is being included in the build and is on the runtime classpath.

Comment: Oh, derp. Okay, I fixed that too. Thank you so much! I've spent hours trying to make this work..